# Dynamic IP set up in IIS for secure an application access

Tags: ip, iis

We have an application needs to be accessed by our sites and for security purpose we restrict the access with IP. All the sites using dynamic IP and I set up the IP with subnet 255.255.0.0 for all the sites. But for some sites, their IP is changing all the 4 numbers and so they cannot access the site. How can I set up an IP in IIS for those sites? Because it is changing all numbers.

Comment: do you control the DHCP and DNS servers? if so, it sounds like your pool configuration is wrong on at least one DHCP server. is this an internal or external network (eg do you get IPs from someone else, or do you define your own)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control access by IP, then the people you want to let in have to have known, static IP addresses, for the reason you have discovered.

Alternative security methods include authentication via [passwords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx) and/or by issuing [client certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732996.aspx).